# Implementation of a a binary search tree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently working with Binary Search Trees and I am having trouble understanding the question for this homework I am doing.

Question:

Draw the binary search tree that results from the following sequence of insertions: 57, 23, 14, 31, 71, 89, 67, 63, 13, 59. **Draw the tree after each two insertions, i.e. after inserting 23, 31, 89, 63 and 59**

So, I have done the first part where I draw the entire trees given the sequence of insertions, but can someone explain what the next part in bold is asking for? It's very vague to me and I can't seem to understand what it wants me to do. What does it mean after each two insertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means start with an empty tree,  then insert 57, then insert 23, then draw what the tree looks like at that point.

Then insert 14, then insert 31, then draw what the tree looks like at that point.

Keep going like that, drawing the tree after inserting two more values.

By the way, there are several algorithms for inserting into a binary search tree. I assume you are given the algorithm to use, and that it is probably a simple binary search tree. Balanced trees are much more complicated but also more useful.

Comment: I see, I was thinking that, but it seemed a bit too obvious or easy? I was thinking there was something more complicated.

Comment: That's the direct meaning of what you wrote. And yes, it does seem easy but a typical homework problem.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this!